# Navigation drawer and Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

Having a problem getting my navigation drawer and toolbar to work on my app. When I first load the app, it works, but when I navigate to another page, it crashes unless I take `setUpNavigationDrawer()` out. The toolbar shows on all activities, but the back button won't work.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bestworkouts.sheikoworkout/com.bestworkouts.sheikoworkout.MyWorkout}: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.bestworkouts.sheikoworkout.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUp
(int, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout, android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)'
 on a null object reference
```

Here is my setUp code:

```
protected void setUpNavigationDrawer() {

    ListView navigationListView;

    List<NavigationDrawerItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_agenda, AppConstant.DRAWER_HOME));
    items.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder, AppConstant.DRAWER_MY_WORKOUT));
    items.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery, AppConstant.DRAWER_MAXES));
    items.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete, AppConstant.DRAWER_PROGRESS));
    items.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences, AppConstant.DRAWER_WORKOUTS));
    items.add(new NavigationDrawerItem(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help, AppConstant.DRAWER_HELP_AND_FEEDBACK));

    //initialize the drawer fragment
    mDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    mDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolBar);

    NavigationDrawerAdapter navigationDrawerAdapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), items);
    //initialize the list view for navigation drawer
    navigationListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_list);
    navigationListView.setAdapter(navigationDrawerAdapter);
```

In my other classes onCreate:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_workout);
    mToolBar =activateToolbar();
    setUpNavigationDrawer();
```

and my_workout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context=".MyWorkout">

<include android:id="@+id/app_bar"
         layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listViewWorkouts"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment_navigation_drawer, drawer_layout are both working as it does work on the first activity on start up! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your setup isn't exactly clear, but with the code you've given, there's apparently no `NavigationDrawerFragment` in the `Activity`'s layout, and `mDrawerFragment` is null there. Notice that you're calling `setContentView(R.layout.my_workout)`, which makes that the `Activity`'s entire layout, and it does not appear to contain a `NavigationDrawerFragment`, unless it's in the toolbar `<include>`, but I wouldn't think so.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add the fragment and drawer layout to my two other layouts! doh!